# How to use PhantomJS along with node.js for scraping?

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, phantomjs

I have installed node-phantom by `npm install node-phantom` but when I am running this code, it is giving  `Cannot find module 'webpage'` this error

```
var webpage = require('webpage').create(),
    url = "https://www.example.com/cba/abc",
    hrefs = new Array();
webpage.open(url,function(status){
    if(status=="success"){
        var results = page.evaluate(function(){
            $("#endpoints").each(function() {
                  hrefs.push($(this).attr("href"));
            });
            return hrefs;
        });
        console.log(JSON.stringify(results));
        phantom.exit();
    }
});
```

Comment: check in the node_module folder whether there is a webpage module is present or not

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't require the webpage module in node-phantom. You would use its API to get a representation of the webpage module. It has to be done this way, because PhantomJS has a different execution runtime from node.js. They generally can't use the same modules. That is why there are bridges between those two execution environments like [**node-phantom**](https://github.com/alexscheelmeyer/node-phantom) and [**phantom**](https://github.com/sgentle/phantomjs-node). They essentially replicate the API of PhantomJS to be used in node.js.

As per documentation, you don't require the webpage, you get a page instead:

```
var phantom = require('node-phantom');
phantom.create(function(err,ph) {
  return ph.createPage(function(err,page) {
    // do something with page: basically your script
  });
});
```

You won't be able to just copy and paste existing PhantomJS code. There are differences, so you will have to study the API (basically the README on github).

Complete translation of your code:

```
var phantom = require('node-phantom');
phantom.create(function(err,ph) {
  return ph.createPage(function(err,page) {
    page.open(url,function(status){
      if(status=="success"){
        page.evaluate(function(){
          hrefs = [];
          $("#endpoints").each(function() {
            hrefs.push($(this).attr("href"));
          });
          return hrefs;
        }, function(err, results){
          console.log(JSON.stringify(results));
          ph.exit();
        });
      }
    });
  });
});
```

[`page.evaluate`](http://phantomjs.org/api/webpage/method/evaluate.html) is still sandboxed, so you can't use variables from the outside like `hrefs`.